# Location value misbehaves on an Office365 account

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have an issue with setting location value for an Office 365 Business Premium account appointment in OWA.

code for getting location:

```
  function getLocation() {
    const $dLoc = $.Deferred();
    try {
        Office.context.mailbox.item.location.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          $dLoc.resolve(asyncResult.value);
        }
        else {
          $dLoc.reject(translate.getTranslation('ERROR_GETTING_LOCATION'));
        }
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      $dLoc.reject(e);
    }
    return $dLoc.promise();
  }
```

code for setting location:

```
  function applyLocation() {
    const $dLoc = $.Deferred();
    try {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.location.setAsync(_appointmentInfo.loc, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          $dLoc.resolve();
        }
        else {
          $dLoc.reject(translate.getTranslation('ERROR_SETTING_LOCATION'));
        }
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      $dLoc.reject(e);
    }
    return $dLoc.promise();
  }
```

This works fine on an exchange 2016 on-premise server both in the native Outlook clients(MAC and WIN) and OWA.

In an Office 365 Business Premium account it also works just fine in the Outlook native client , but in OWA (https://outlook.office.com/owa/...) I can get/set the location just fine programmatically, but whatever value I set does not get preserved upon meeting/appointment save/sent.

One difference I notice is that on Exchange 2016 on-premise the location is plain text in the location field in OWA, while in Office365 OWA the location has some html applied to it and it has an X button as in the below image:

[image: x button on location]

Any idea why this happens, why it works for exchange and does not work for Office365 OWA?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. We apologize for any inconvenience this has caused and are currently working to fix this issue as quickly as we can.

Comment: Great news, thank you. Anywhere I can track when this is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

We have fixed the bug and the fix should be available in build <16.00.2149.000> or later. Depending on the release channel, getting an update build can take anywhere from 4-8 weeks.